# Optimal way to append to numpy array when dealing with large dimensions

Tags: list, numpy, append

I am working with a json file that consists of approximately 17,000 3x1 arrays denoting the coordinates.

Currently,I have an image of 1024x1024 dimensions(which I have flattend),and I am using np.hstack to add the 3x1 array to that image ,this gives me a 1d array of dimension 1048579x1

My objective is to create a final array of dimension 1048579x17,000.
Unfortunately list.append and np.append are not working in this case,because it's consuming too much memory.I tried running this on colab pro,but the memory consumption is too high which causes the session to crash

My current code is as follows

```
image=cv2.imread('image_name.jpg',0)
shape=image.shape
flat_img=image.ravel()
print(flat_img.shape)
#Here data consists of 17,000 entries each of which is a 3x1 list
with open('data.json') as f:
    json1_str = f.read()
    json1_data=json.loads(json1_str)

local_coordinates=[]
for i in range(len(json1_data)):
    local_coord=json1_data[i]['local_coordinate']
    local_coord=np.array(local_coord)
    new_arr=np.hstack((flat_img,local_coord))
    new_arr=new_arr.tolist()
    local_coordinates.append(new_arr) #
```

Is there an optimal way to stack all the 1048579 1d arrays to create the final matrix which can be used for training purposes?

Comment: How much memory do you expect the final array to use?  The joining method doesn't make much difference in total usage - you need space for at least 2 copies - the originals and the final.

Comment: i will compute it and let you know

Comment: Note that the appending should take at least 17 GiB of RAM and the final array creation must take the same space resulting in 34 GiB of RAM taken. This is a lot. Why do you repeat the same image data 17000 times (with only a 0.0001% difference)?

Comment: No wonder colab was crashing,thanks for the input.I am just going to save the 3x1 array in a seperate file.Then during training I will load it,and then concatenate it with the original image.Let me know,if i am on the right track.I am using this in a conditional autoencoder.